# Alternative to application:handleIntent:completionHandler: on WatchOS

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, sirikit

iOS's `[application:handleIntent:completionHandler:]` allows to handle SiriKit intents inside of AppDelegate class on iOS targets.

I wonder whether there is an alternative for this method on WatchOS target as well? What I need is the similar function which handles SiriKit requests on WatchOS and responds to WatchOS intention extension with a result of type *INIntentResponse* – the same way as it works on iOS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that such method is present in WKExtensionDelegate in WatchOS 5.0+: `handleIntent:completionHandler:`

Here is an example:

```
func handle(_ intent: INIntent, completionHandler: @escaping (INIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    let result = INStartWorkoutIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: nil)

    completionHandler(result)
}
```